# Auto generating ivy.xml file in Apache Ivy

Tags: xml, apache, ant, ivy, dependency-management

My aim is to be able to auto-generate ivy.xml file by analyzing the Java source code.
That is, a developer need not determine the external jars to be included, it should be automatically detected from source code (.java files).  Is there any way to do this using some script or tool or anything.
I did come across this answer ([Apache Ivy: Dependency Ivy FIles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363580/apache-ivy-dependency-ivy-files)), but it requires the jars to be already present in a directory from where they are searched for GAV and written to ivy.xml.
Further efforts brought me to tools like JarAnalyzer, Dependency Finder etc, but they seem to analyze .class files instead of .java files.
My requirement is to be able to identify the jars to be included in classpath by analyses of source code itself. Any help would be appreciated!

**Update:** If it is sure that this can't be achieved, then could anyone please justify as to why is this automation not feasible? Some reasons as to why dependencies can't be resolved from analysis of source code? Any suggestions are welcome!!

Comment: Not a simple problem to solve.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor: I do realize the difficulty level. However, a solution with certain constraints would also do. Any ideas/suggestions?