# Running axis2 code generated by soapui

Tags: java, soap

I am using soapui to generate my axis2 java code. Now I have a build.xml and a java file. How do I go about running ths as a standalone java application. What ide am I supposed to use and how do I compile this code(if i directly paste this code into netbeans there are so many jars which I am having to add. Even after this some classes are not found and I am unable to compile it). What are the external jars that I need to add. Are there any good tutorials for this. Also does anyone know of any easy way to convert a wsdl url to javastandalone  code for querying the web application.

Answer (score 1):

You can import an Ant project into NetBeans as a free-form project.

[NetBeans Freeform Projects](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html#free-form)

If you feel like an adventure, you can manually convert your Ant project to Maven

[Convert Ant project to Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029501/how-to-convert-ant-project-to-maven-project)

There are many tools for generating Java code from WSDL. Most modern IDE's have built-in plugins for this purpose (Eclipse, NetBeans, IDEA]. Since you are using Axis2 you can also use the `wsdl2java` command line tool.

[Axis 2: Creating Client Code from WSDL](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html)

Comment: Okay. I generated the java file into axis2 and added the jars. But how do i call this file. How di i actually get the soap service working.

Comment: I created java project and add axis library. But how can I run it?