# whats the correct way to I open web application created on netbeans in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, web, netbeans, web-applications, project

What I did was simply open the project in eclipse. It opened but showed be 100s of errors.
Refer picture:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/weHwx.png]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get your Netbeans project into Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21535023/2985643)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get your Netbeans project into Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21535023/how-to-get-your-netbeans-project-into-eclipse)