# Java - How to incorporate a downloaded library to Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have downloaded a java libary from the internet that I hope to use in my Java project on Eclipse. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with how to do this. Looking at the downloaded folder, it has a build.xml file. What am I supposed to do with this? Here's a screenshot of the folder:

[image]

Sorry, if this is a silly question. I'm really new to Java programming, so if this is a duplicate, I'll gladly mark it as such.

Comment: This might be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse

Comment: Thanks for your help. The post you linked to shows how to import a .jar file. I know how to do this. However, I seem to have a project folder instead of a .jar file. And I don't know how to introduce this to my Eclipse IDE as a project.

Comment: This is a maven project. Steps to import maven project into eclipse is detailed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061094/importing-maven-project-into-eclipse

Comment: my bad .. I thought you wanted to use the downloaded library as a dependency. What @Haroon has mentioned above should work for Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the solution to this question. The project in question was a Netbeans project I got from my friend and I tried to import it to Eclipse. There are ways to import Netbeans project into Eclipse, but once I clarified the issue with my friend, I simply opened it in Netbeans and it worked great.

If you need it, though, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21535023/how-to-get-your-netbeans-project-into-eclipse) is what I found for importing Netbeans projects into Eclipse.