# Difference between Jenkins and AntHillPro

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, ant, anthill

In our Project we are currently using AntHillPro, we would like to move to Jenkins, for this I have the following queries:-

1> Does all the task that is possible to do in AntHillPro will be done in Jenkins.

2> Possible dollar cost savings for Using Jenkins instead of AntHillPro.

3> All our projects are in ant, want to migrate it to maven, does Jenkins support that.

Comment: Following. We are on the same issue too.

Comment: Regarding 3. Jenkins support both Maven and Ant, you would have to convert the project manually though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029501/how-to-convert-ant-project-to-maven-project

Answer (score 3):

> 1> Does all the task that is possible to do in AntHillPro will be done in Jenkins.

Yes, most of things are possible, which are commonly used.

> 2> Possible dollar cost savings for Using Jenkins instead of AntHillPro.

Jenkins is free, AHP will cost some $.

> 3> All our projects are in ant, want to migrate it to maven, does Jenkins support that.

Jenkins supports Ant, Maven, Shell Script, Windows batch commands.